# Prove that an isomorphism Φ: F[x] → F[x] preserves irreducibility.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Let $\Phi : F[x] \to F[x]$ be an isomorphism such that $\Phi(a) = a$ for every $a \in F$. Show that $f(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$ if and only if $\Phi(f(x))$ is irreducible in $F[x]$.

Any help on how to go about starting my contrapositive proof please

Comment: "Irreducibility of an isomorphism" ??

Answer (score 3):

$\Phi$ is an isomorphism.  If $f = g h$, then $\Phi(f) = \Phi(g)\Phi(h)$ and vice versa.  Since $\Phi$ maps the degree zero polynomials (the constants) to themselves, $g$ and $\Phi(g)$ are either both constants or both non-constants.  Likewise for $h$ and $\Phi(h)$.  Apply definition of irreducible.  Done.

Comment: Where is it used that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism? Doesn't all of the arguments hold for any endomorphism?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout : The correct alternative pairs are isomorphism/homomorphism and automorphism/endomorphism, not isomorphism/endomorphism.  Further, the endomorphism fixing the base field and taking $x \mapsto (x^2 - 1)$ does not preserve irreducibility.

Comment: You are right about the reason why I asked this question, I would still like to know why $\Phi$ needs to be an isomorphism.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout : "Further, the endomorphism fixing the base field and taking $x \mapsto (x^2−1)$ does not preserve irreducibility."

Comment: I don't see where you're going with this. I am aware of that $x\mapsto (x^2-1)$ doesn't work, however I don't see why it is required that the map also is an isomorphism.

$\Phi(gh)=\Phi(g)\phi(h)$ is true for any homomorphism, also $x\mapsto (x^2-1)$ fix the base field, so there has to be something more?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout : $x$ is irreducible.  Its image $x^2 - 1$ is not.  One way to assign blame for this failure is that the two factors do not have preimages because the endomorphism fails to be an automorphism.  An automorphism guarantees a factorization on either end of the map is the image or a preimage of factorization on the other end.  The set of endomorphisms cannot make this guarantee.